# Cannot implicity convert type. An explicit conversion exist

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain me why i am getting following below errors and how to fix this? This is my code:

```
    public enum DataSource
    {
        SqlServer,
        Csv,
        Oracle
    }

    public interface IRepo
    {
    }

    public interface IRepository<T> where T :class 
    {
         IEnumerable<T> GetRecords();
    }

    public static IRepo GetRepository(DataSource repositoryType)
    {
        IRepo repo;

        switch (repositoryType)
        {
            case DataSource.Csv:
                repo = new CsvRepository("path"); //perhaps path shoudln't br right passed right here - so where?
                break;

            case DataSource.SqlServer:
                repo = new SqlRepository();
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Repository Type");
        }

        return repo;
    }

public class CsvRepository : IRepository<InputData>
{

   private string _path;

   public CsvRepository(string path)
   {
       _path = path;
   }

   public IEnumerable<IBasic> GetRecords()
   {
       return from line in File.ReadLines(_path)
              select line.Split(',') into parts
              where parts.Length == 3
              select new InputData { Name = parts[0], X = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]), Y = Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]) };
    }
}

//other repositories:
public class OracleRepository : IRepository<OtherDataType>
{
..
}
...
```

I got error on below lines:

```
 repo = new CsvRepository();
 repo = new SqlRepository();
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'CsvRepository' to 'IRepo'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). Cannot implicitly convert type 'SqlRepository' to 'IRepo'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

**Bonus question (if possible):**
As you see i want to pass path of file into ctor of CsvRepository - if i use Factory pattern i am sure this shouldn't be passwed from My factory method, how to do it properly. Also for SqlRepository i will need probably to pass some information...

Comment: are your Repository classes inheriting from IRepo interface?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: if you want to be really precise, the Repository classes aren't *inheriting* from `IRepo` - but they are **implementing** the `IRepo` interface (inheritance is only possible from another class - not an interface)

Comment: "Bonus question (if possible)", where is it? Also, please post a [mcve]

Comment: I added missing code. See now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that your `IRepository<T>` is not inheriting from `IRepo`, so you can write this:

```
 IRepository<InputData> repo = new CsvRepository();
```

but not :

```
IRepo repo = new CsvRepository();
```

For that you would need to inherit your `IRepository<T>` from `IRepo` as right now there is no relationship of Repository classes with that interface.

So you will need to do :

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IRepo where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetRecords();
}
```

See the [example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zGgcME). 
Hope it helps.

Comment: ah i forgot to inherit ... You right, by the way is it really correct just to do this empty IRepo for Factory or it's better to make it as IRepository<InputData> to get more concrete object with methods after getting specific object repository from Factory? P.S Can you also answer on my bonus question please.

Comment: i think the bonus question is more of a software engineering stackexchange or codereview.stackexcahange related, consider posting a question on that there.

Comment: Ok and about first question from my comment?

Comment: `IRepository<InputData>` seems enough as you have nothing in `IRepo`

Comment: Thanks - last one: Where would you pass information to specific repositories once taken from Factory?